# Error during Yarn install when deploying to Netlify

Tags: reactjs, netlify, yarn-v2, yarn-lock.json

I am unable to deploy my React App to Netlify.
Its encontering  Error during Yarn install when building the App.

[Link to build error](https://app.netlify.com/sites/venerable-praline-1acded/deploys/6441237cb0a87217b5fc36b4)

I tried changing the build command from npm run build to yarn run build yet still not working

[image: image showing the error]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the build error log, the deploy didn't include the yarn.lock/package.json. Either that or the yarn version was different than the one the package.json file was based on.

If you see that your package.json is getting deployed, I would recommend try to clear the cache and try running the CI again.

There's helpful Github thread on the matter: https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/2948

If this didn't solve your problem, please provide us with more info on how did you do your deployment and what files did you include!

Comment: Added the yarn.lock file but still didn't work